# Google maps place popup box and size

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am a complete novice when it comes to the Google Maps API. Hope someone can help with a quick question

Below is my code, firstly how can I control the size of the map and also how do I make it so when the marker is clicked a pop up box with the address shows?

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.google-maps').gmap3({
                    map:{
                        address: "PL1 3LF",
                        options:{
                            zoom: 10,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            mapTypeControl: false,
                            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
                            },
                            navigationControl: true,
                            scrollwheel: false,
                            streetViewControl: false
                        }
                    },
                    marker:{
    values:[
      {address:"PL21 0SZ"},
      {address:"PL1 3LF"}
    ]
}
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Size of the map is controlled by setting size of containing element. See [your plugins docs](http://gmap3.net/en/pages/5-getting-started/)

For the popups: take the second code snippet from http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41 and try to change the 'mouseover' event to click-event instead. Also edit the lines saying

```
infowindow.setContent(context.data)
```

to fit your needs, for example you can use context.address instead of data.

Answer (score 0):

try google maps instead of g3maps.. [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) . A complete solution for geo positioning, markers, animation, path etc.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [simple map builder](https://mapbuildr.com/buildr), If all you want to do is add custom markers with popup windows it should do the trick. You don't need to use the API unless you want to do something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling the size of the map is pretty easy. You are placing the map into .google-maps so just adjust the size of it:

```
.google-maps {
   width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

And the popup can be done via events on marker:

```
marker: {
    values: [{
        latLng: [48.8620722, 2.352047],
        data: "Paris !"
    }, {
        address: "86000 Poitiers, France",
        data: "Poitiers : great city !"
    }],
    options: {
        draggable: false
    },
    events: {
        click: function(marker, event, context) {
            var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                infowindow = $(this).gmap3({
                    get: {
                        name: "infowindow"
                    }
                });
            if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                infowindow.setContent(context.data);
            } else {
                $(this).gmap3({
                    infowindow: {
                        anchor: marker,
                        options: {
                            content: context.data
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```